permisssion denied, authentications that can continue (publickey, password) Raspberry PI
Specs:

Pi Model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
Client OS: Ubuntu 22.04 Pro

I am trying to ssh into raspberry Pi from outside my LAN, but it is giving me the same Permission denied, please try again error again and again.
I have a user ammar on raspberry pi 4 model B. When I attempt to connect it locally from my LAN, it successfully connects with both password authentication, and rsa/ed25519 keys. But the problem arise when i attempt to connect to it from outside my lan, from internet. I have applied port forwarding on my router, and it is (presumably) forwarding the traffic successfully, the problem is just with the authentication.
Here is the verbose output when i tried to log into Pi locally:
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ammar/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ammar/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 192.168.10.55
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 25: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.10.55 [192.168.10.55] port 5555.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/pikey_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/pikey_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.10.55:5555 as 'ammar'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:7aOM9kWddB7SNBKKWxsfNbPkJdUfDQY/bHJ4ZWz4ELA
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ammar/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[192.168.10.55]:5555' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ammar/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 4 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/pikey_rsa RSA SHA256:p6VV6w7qOT7u+rN6G8SXaOQM8KNUlYh9FMPuaF81dRc explicit agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ammar@192.168.10.55's password: 
Authenticated to 192.168.10.55 ([192.168.10.55]:5555) using "password".

And here is the verbose output from ssh command when tried from outside the LAN:
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ammar/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 25: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 39.56.11.167 [39.56.11.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ammar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52
debug1: compat_banner: no match: dropbear_0.52
debug1: Authenticating to 39.56.11.167:22 as 'ammar'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:My9Mo/CklKra5xqhiWeChM6BljBf/QcBf31+bISgHb0
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ammar/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '39.56.11.167' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ammar/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 4 keys
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB - corresponding algo not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
debug1: Will attempt key: ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB RSA SHA256:p6VV6w7qOT7u+rN6G8SXaOQM8KNUlYh9FMPuaF81dRc agent
debug1: Will attempt key: ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB ED25519 SHA256:RUeQBVo2UleFIm3xExmboiYrI0DbmxzQr6T4V52Jao0 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB ED25519 SHA256:OPmahidCUD1KFLTD5zvmZY8iId89pta22loQ/wtPOTY agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB RSA SHA256:p6VV6w7qOT7u+rN6G8SXaOQM8KNUlYh9FMPuaF81dRc agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB ED25519 SHA256:RUeQBVo2UleFIm3xExmboiYrI0DbmxzQr6T4V52Jao0 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: ammar@ammar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB ED25519 SHA256:OPmahidCUD1KFLTD5zvmZY8iId89pta22loQ/wtPOTY agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ammar/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ammar@39.56.11.167's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
ammar@39.56.11.167's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
ammar@39.56.11.167's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ammar@39.56.11.167: Permission denied (publickey,password).


You're not connecting to the same host in both situations.
For your "log into Pi locally" session the logs say:
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3

For your "outside the LAN" session the logs say:
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52

So, your port forwarding configuration on your router is apparently wrong and
is forwarding you to the wrong host.

You are correct Waxrat. Thanks a lot for pointing out the correct problem. I checked the ssh version of my router, and it came out to be Dropbear 0.52. My router was not actually forwarding the traffic to the designated ip, it was trying to connect with its own ssh server.

can you specify why my router is behaving like this? That it is not forwarding traffic to my raspberry pi, and trying to connect with its own ssh server?

Could be a bug in the router. Could be a config issue in the router. You could try a different TCP port instead of the default 22. Which is generally a good idea because the script kiddies are less likely to find you then.

Problem is resolved. I was actually trying to access the Raspberry Pi through port forwarding from within my router's LAN. Port forwarding is expected to work for the requests coming from outside the LAN. So when I tried the same procedure from another network, everything worked as expected.
